# How to partition Java List to get one list with specific condition & other with all intersected?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to partition `Java List` to get the following two types of list:

1. List which contains elements satisfying a specific condition
2. List which contain all elements but they will be the intersection of each other

My current **working approach** is using `forEach` as below:

```
Map<String, Set<Attribute>> applicableAttributeMap = new HashMap<>();

Set<Attribute> unionMandatoryAttributes = new HashSet<>();
Set<Attribute> intersectedAttributes = new HashSet<>();

givenNames.forEach(givenName -> {
    List<Attribute> applicableAttributes = getAllApplicableAttributes(givenName);  //function to retrieve List<Attribute> by passing givenName
    if (applicableAttributes != null && !applicableAttributes.isEmpty()) {
        unionMandatoryAttributes.addAll(
                applicableAttributes
                        .stream()
                        .filter(Attribute::getIsRequired)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        );

        if (intersectedAttributes.isEmpty()) {
            intersectedAttributes.addAll(applicableAttributes);
        }
        intersectedAttributes.retainAll(applicableAttributes);
    }
});

applicableAttributeMap.put(UnionMandatory, unionMandatoryAttributes);
applicableAttributeMap.put(IntersectedAll, intersectedAttributes);
```

I'm trying to simplify above code block using `partitioningBy`, but I'm unable to get the desired output. I'm not able to collect another list which has all the elements along with `Map`'s `key` as `String`.

**Here is my `partitioningBy` approach**:

```
Map<Boolean, Set<Attribute>> applicableMap = givenNames
        .stream()
        .flatMap(s -> getAllApplicableAttributes(s).stream())
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                Attribute::getIsRequired,
                Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),Collectors.toSet())
        ));
```

How I can create the `Map<String , Set<Attributes>>` which will satisfy the condition given in **working approach** or any other simplified solution?

(Note: So my goal is to achieve the exact what's happening with **working approach** I might have missed something in explaining the problem. But the bottom line is to get the result as same as **working approach** by using something like `partitioningBy` or any better approach than what I've done.)

Comment: The `intersectedAttributes` not interset with all the collection as you will only add new items if the collection is empty and then potentially remove from it based on the intersection with the next list element. I think the line `if (intersectedAttributes.isEmpty()) {` needs to be removed, but then you said that it's the working solution so perhaps try to redefine your goals.

Comment: You can see that after if block I'm doing `intersectedAttributes.retainAll(applicableAttributes);`.  `addAll` will be executed only at the first time or `intersectedAttributes` list is empty. Later onwards, `retainAll` will be executed. I don't see any problem in that. So my goal is to achieve the exact what's happening with **working approach** I might have missed something in explaining problem. But bottom line is to get result I'm getting using `partitioningBy` or any other `stream` related function.

Comment: I've updated my question to brief my end-goal.

Comment: @AshwinK - I think @Ilya Gazman is right with his question. Or are you saying that if the `retainAll` happens to remove all that then you wish to start with the intersection anew?

Comment: @AshwinK - in my opinion you need to retrieve union-ed and itersected attributes separately, i.e. iterating with the givenNames.stream() twice. The reason is that whereas the unioned attributes operates on flated stream, the intersected attributes needs to intersect the individual attributes collection.

Comment: Your current approach is *not* working. Your `intersectedAttributes` may become empty due to a `retainAll` operation when there is no attribute common to all sets, then, you’ll suddenly do an `addAll` with the next set and possibly end up with a non-empty set where the intersection should be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating twice over the `givenNames` looks like the best approach:

```
    Map<String, Set<Attribute>> applicableAttributeMap = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> givenNames = ImmutableList.copyOf(....);

    Set<Attribute> unionMandatoryAttributes =   
             givenNames.stream()
                       .map(this::getAllApplicableAttributes)
                       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                       .filter(Attribute::getIsRequired)
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Set<Attribute> intersectedAttributes = ImmutableSet.of();
    if (givenNames.size() > 0) {
        intersectedAttributes = this.getAllApplicableAttributes(givesNames.get(0));         
        for (int i = 1; i < givenNames.size(); i++) {
             intersectedAttributes = Sets.intersection(intersectedAttributes, getAllApplicableAttributes(givesNames.get(i)));                           
        }
    }

    applicableAttributeMap.put("UnionMandatory", unionMandatoryAttributes);
    applicableAttributeMap.put("IntersectedAll", intersectedAttributes);
}
```

Note that this code relies on Guava's `ImmutableList`, `ImmutableSet` and `Sets.intersection`.

Be also aware of the doubled number of calls to `getAllApplicableAttributes` in this code.

Comment: Thanks @Michal for your response. If we consider performance then what I've posted originally is better than this solutions. As `Sets. intersection` will again make internal looping. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AshwinK: The `Sets.intersection` call needs to figure out the intersection exactly as the `intersectedAttributes.retainAll` one. What is extra in my version of the code is the second iteration over the given names and also variable creations  (like the `intersectedAttributes = new HashSet<>`). On the other hand, it fixes the error with starting the intersection anew if the `retainAll` removed everything.

Comment: @Holger: thanks for the comment regarding the `if`  That is correct again )

Comment: Since you are now not relying on mutable sets, you could also use `Set<Attribute> intersectedAttributes = Collections.emptySet();` as declaration with initial value.

Comment: @AshwinK - as for performance, the only probably issue concerns the doubled number of calls to `getAllApplicableAttributes`. However, if that operation is expensive, then this could be easily solved by retrieving all the attributes upfront and referring to them after that.

Answer (score -1):

Edited after the comments pointed out I misread the question.

**My revised solution:**

You can actually do the intersection with a Stream for the most part, if you just intialize the Set outside of the Stream. Like this:

```
    Set<String> intersected = new HashSet<>();
    givenNames.stream()
            .map(gn ->  getAllApplicableAttributes(gn)) // yields Stream of List<Attribute> per given Name
            .forEach(list -> {
                if ( intersected.isEmpty() ){
                    intersected.addAll(list);
                } else {
                    intersected.removeIf(x -> !list.contains(x)); // remove attributes if not present in this iteration
                }
            });
```

As other people have mentioned above, filtering makes more sense than partitioning.

```
Set<Attribute>> unionMandatory = givenNames
        .stream()
        .flatMap(s -> getAllApplicableAttributes(s).stream())
        .filter(Attribute::getIsRequired)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Because `intersected` can't be created by a Stream, it makes no sense to create the final Map from a Stream, so I would just put both these sets into the Map as you did in your working approach.

Comment: This is IMHO quite far from the requirement. It fulfills the union-ed attribute requirement but it fails on the intersected attributes requirement fully. The intersected attributes shall be a/intersected b/contain attributes regardless of reuired / required not. In my opinion you have only those not required and are missing the intersection point at all.

Comment: Except for removing the obsolete `Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), …)`, this is exactly what the OP already posted in the question. The result is the same. It even has the same error of using `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` at a point where it is too late, as when `getAllApplicableAttributes(s)` returns `null`, the attempt to invoke `stream()` on it will fail with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Holger - it might fulfill OP's ***partitioningBy approach*** but IMHO it does not fullfil the ***working approach***

Comment: You are correct, `NullPointerException` might return null & it will give exception. Seems you are right, `partitioningBy approach` will not work to replace **working approach**

Comment: You are right. I completely missed the intersected part. I thought the issue was the partitioning wasn't working as expected. My bad. Going to edit my answer now.